# how to mask one of the ContentPanels in AccordionLayoutContainer

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

There is a accordionLayoutContainer in my project,and i want to mask one of the contentpanels,i use this code:

```
ContentPanel cp1 = new ContentPanel(appearance);
cp1.mask("message");
```

but the whole accordionLayoutContainer was mask,not the cp1.
thanks for suggestions!

Comment: I hava solived the problem,use this code: cp1.getBody().mask("message"). but another problem is that the String message do not display in the middle of the cp body.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp1.getBody().mask("message")
```

use this code to mask one of the contentpanels in accordionLayoutContainer.But the other problem is that the string message do not display in the middle of the contentpanels body.sorry for not showing the picture.